# Marginal Distribution of Hierarchal Model Normal distribution with unknown mean and precision

Tags: bayesian, gamma-distribution, hierarchical-bayesian

I am trying to use a Hierarchical model where there I have a normal distribution with random mean and precision:

$$
y \sim N(\mu, \tau)\\
\mu \sim N(M, T)\\
\tau \sim Gamma(\alpha, \beta)
$$

I'm trying to marginalize out $\mu$ and $\tau$ to find $p(y | M, T, \alpha, \beta)$. I think I can marginalize out $\mu$:
$$
\int d\mu d\tau N(y | \mu,\tau) N(\mu | M,T) Gamma(\tau | \alpha, \beta)\\
=\int d\tau N\left(y | M, \frac{1}{1/\tau + 1/T}\right)Gamma(\tau |\alpha, \beta)\\
$$
I'm not sure how to complete the integral over $\tau$. I know that if T=0 the distribution would be a student-t but other than that I'm stuck.

Comment: The model is not hierarchical. The integral cannot be solved in closed form.

Comment: okay good to know thanks. Just out of curiosity why do you say it's not hierarchical? My definition seems pretty similar to what is found in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_hierarchical_modeling. I just haven't included the subscripts and in this case and I haven't included a prior. Maybe you would prefer the term compound probability distribution.

Comment: A hierarchical model has a second prior specified over the parameters of a first prior.